# WSO2 - disable HTTPS

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

How can I disable HTTPS for WSO2 Api Manager (admin/gw/other components)?
We want to SSL-terminate on our front load-balancers - and not on the end WSO2-products. If I visit port 9763 I'll get redirected to 9443.
We're running 2.1.0 deployed with the docker-images.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do the following,

1. Go to the $WSO2_HOME/repository/conf and open carbon.xml, and
   uncomment

   ```
   <EnableHTTPAdminConsole>true</EnableHTTPAdminConsole>
   ```
2. Disable secure cookie parameter in
   $WSO2_HOME/repository/conf/tomcat/carbon/WEB-INF/web.xml file as
   well.

   ```
   <session-config> 
    <cookie-config> 
     <secure>false</secure> 
    </cookie-config> 
   </session-config>
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I still get redirected to https/9443 for published though, is that maybe another config? Basically I want all components to run on http as they will have external SSL-terminating proxy-servers in front of them (or be internal traffic between the components)

Comment: Hi, is there a solution with all configuration files provided by wso2 ? thx

Comment: Abimaran Thanks. 
@DavidKarlsen I have the same issue with store as well. I tried changing the urls in api-manager.xml as well. It redirects to http. But when I try to sign in it redirects to https. 
Maybe the redirection url is set to https somewhere in the jaggery app. Abimaran Any clue about this.

Comment: In store it happens after calling the redirector.jag. It has a redirection to the HTTPS URL. Whe I tried to redirect it to the http utl by editing the redirector.jag. But it ended up after calling the http://localhost:9763/store/site/blocks/tag/tag-cloud/ajax/list.jag?tenant=carbon.super. How can we solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the system configuration of David doesn't introduce security issues following should work. (If the load balancers and WSO2 products are in the same private network or VPC there should be no additional security problems)

**Note: Following approaches were tested with single tenant (super tenant) scenario only.**

1. For the carbon console, the approach Abimaran has suggested should work.
2. For the store component couple of changes are required.

Replace the content in repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/site/themes/wso2/templates/user/login/redirector.jag with following.

```
<%
include("/jagg/jagg.jag");
var site = require("/site/conf/site.json");

var tenant = jagg.getTenantDomain();
var queryString = "";

session.put("showLogin", "true");
session.put("redirectToHTTPS", jagg.getHttpsUrl("/site/pages/login.jag")+queryString);
response.sendRedirect(jagg.getHttpsUrl("/site/pages/login.jag") + queryString);
%>
```

Replace the getHttpsUrl function definition in repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/jagg/jagg.jag

```
var getHttpsUrl = function(path, parameters){
    var hostname = "";
    var requestSegments = getRequestSegments();
    var protocol = "https://";
    mod = jagg.module("manager");
    var requestUrl = request.getRequestURL();

    if(requestUrl.indexOf("https://") != -1 ){
        hostname = mod.getHTTPsURL();
        hostname = hostname.replace("https://","");
    } else if (requestUrl.indexOf("http://") != -1 ) {
        hostname = mod.getHTTPURL();
        hostname = hostname.replace("http://","");
        protocol = "http://";
    }

    // if the site is fronted by a proxy server
    if(isReverseProxyEnabled()){
         hostname = site.reverseProxy.host ;
         //if a custom https port is used
         if(site.reverseProxy.hosts_port){
            hostname = hostname + ":" + site.reverseProxy.hosts_port;
         }
    }        

    return protocol + hostname + url(path, parameters);
}
```

3. For the publisher component, the following change should be done.

repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/publisher/site/themes/wso2/templates/user/login/template.jag

replace the part

```
<%      if(request.isSecure()){

        if(jagg.getUser() != null){
            response.sendRedirect('index.jag');
        }
%>
```

with

```
<%      if(true){

        if(jagg.getUser() != null){
            response.sendRedirect('index.jag');
        }
%>
```

**Note: The security totally depends on the system architecture. Additionally, the above configurations are independent. If you need to let https access to all components then do all. For particular one, the respective configuration alone should work.**

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In case of version 5.10.0 and windows 10,

> #1 Open "C:\Program Files\WSO2\Identity Server\5.10.0\repository\resources\conf\default.json"
>
> #2 Change three fields

from

```
 "transport.https.properties.scheme": "https",  
 "transport.https.properties.secure": "true",  
 "transport.https.properties.SSLEnabled": "true",
```

to

```
  "transport.https.properties.scheme": "http",
  "transport.https.properties.secure": "false",
  "transport.https.properties.SSLEnabled": "false",
```

> #3 start server batch wso2server.bat
>
> #4 open browser http://localhost:9443/

Answer (score 0):

Disabling SSL on WSO2 API Manager implies changing different files (for the different components that it has), introduces some security problems and in case of update you have to be careful to maintain the same logic (at least figure it out what files to change).

But there is another possibility than disabling HTTPS on WSO2. You can still terminate SSL on your Load Balancer/Reverse Proxy, but the connection between the Load Balancers/Reverse Proxy and WSO2 be a "new" SSL connection that uses the "normal" SSL WSO2 behaviour.

For this, you have to change *deployment.toml* to include the following (assuming Load Balancers/Reverse Proxy serve on the same ports as WSO2 and in a determined hostname that you can set in environment:

```
[server]
hostname = "REPLACE_BY_PUBLIC_DOMAIN"
... 
[apim.devportal]
url = "https://REPLACE_BY_PUBLIC_DOMAIN:${mgt.transport.https.port}/devportal"
```

Then you need to configure your Load Balancer/Reverse Proxy to "Proxy Pass" to WSO2. In the reference below there is the configuration for *NGINX*. For *Apache* can be something like this:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

ErrorLog "/dev/stdout
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common 
CustomLog /dev/stdout common

Listen 9443
Listen 8243
Listen 8280

NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:9443
NameVirtualHost *:8243
NameVirtualHost *:8280

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName REPLACE_BY_PUBLIC_DOMAIN
  Redirect "/" "https://REPLACE_BY_PUBLIC_DOMAIN/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:9443>
    ServerName REPLACE_BY_PUBLIC_DOMAIN

    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN Off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire Off 
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/usr/local/apache2/cert/fullchain.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/usr/local/apache2/cert/privkey.pem"

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off

    ProxyPass / https://REPLACE_BY_WSO2_IP:9443/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://REPLACE_BY_WSO2_IP:9443/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8243>
    ServerName REPLACE_BY_PUBLIC_DOMAIN

    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN Off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire Off 
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/usr/local/apache2/cert/fullchain.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/usr/local/apache2/cert/privkey.pem"

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off

    ProxyPass / https://REPLACE_BY_WSO2_IP:8243/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://REPLACE_BY_WSO2_IP:8243/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8280>
    ServerName REPLACE_BY_PUBLIC_DOMAIN

    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN Off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire Off 
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/usr/local/apache2/cert/fullchain.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/usr/local/apache2/cert/privkey.pem"

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    
    ProxyPass / https://REPLACE_BY_WSO2_IP:8280/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://REPLACE_BY_WSO2_IP:8280/
</VirtualHost>
```

In this case all public ports are the same as the "private" ports.

**Reference**: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/configuring-the-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/#configuring-the-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer