# WSO2 Identity over HTTP (disable HTTPS)

Tags: tomcat, https, wso2-identity-server

I was able to activate the HTTP port (`9763`) but it keeps switching back to HTTPS (`9443`).
Both the admin interface and the `OAUTH2` service point I have created are available on HTTP, but when I try to make an OAUTH2 authentication, right after submitting the username and password, it asks for access permission to the profile claims (`oauth2_consent.do`) and it does this over HTTPS.

How could I have the full interaction with WSO2 on a single port, the HTTP port?

I have already seen this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42881109/wso2-disable-https) but it refers to an older WSO2 version and 5.4.1 is now different.

PS: Please do not switch this discussion to security concerns.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible( I am not 100% sure) by changing following configuration file `<PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml` Search for `<connector` tag and you will find a property `redirectPort` , which according to the tomcat documentations https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html redirects the non ssl requests to ssl port. Anyways this is my guess but you can give it a try.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have already deleted that and redirect (or forward, don't know) still happens. Also removed the HTTPS connector (redirect still happens and fails). Also created two separated services for the 2 connectors (one HTTP and one HTTPS) and redirect (or forward) still happens and fails (due to wrong origin set in header : port -1)